# Default serializer for kafka 0.8.2.0

Tags: apache-kafka

I am setting up Kafka producer using their new KafkaProducer API and getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "key.serializer" which has no default value.
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:124)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:48)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.java:235)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:129)
at com.kafka.producer.App.KafkaProducer(App.java:43)
at com.kafka.producer.App.main(App.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

There seems to be no default serializer and the documentation at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newproducerconfigs and I do not see possible values.

This question is for Kafka 0.8.2.0 version

Comment: could you please share the producer code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The earlier versions of Kafka came with default serializer but that created lot of confusion.

With 0.8.2, you would need to pick a serializer yourself from StringSerializer or ByteArraySerializer that comes with API or build your own.

The API serializers can be found at 
StringSerializer:
http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringSerializer.html
ByteArraySerializer:
http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer.html

So, your solution would be to use one of the below options if you are looking to use default Serializers.

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

or

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you want a StringSerializer, use:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());
```

full example here: https://github.com/CameronGregory/kafka/blob/master/TestProducer.java

Comment: I like this solution as it is not related to strings but to real class / values, so even if something change it'll work !

Comment: what is, we want to send Integer as a value. How should I use Serializer here!!

Comment: From 0.9 onwards there is an [IntegerSerializer](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/IntegerSerializer.html).